# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): Error: Cannot find module './src/data'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babel-loader

I'm getting this error when I try to run my app, I'm using all the same dependencies that I always use so I'm very baffled by this.  I've tried deleting my package-lock.json and node modules a couple of times and tried searching the whole repo for /src/data and found nothing.

More of the error message:

ERROR in ./src/index.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module './src/data'

and this is the ./src/index.js from the error

````
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './components/App';
import store from './store';

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);```

Anyone have any recommendations?
````

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there's a problem with a live version of `core-js-compat` dependency. For a quick fix, you can update your ***package.json*** using

```
"core-js-compat": "^3.4.7"
```

Comment: Thanks!  I just saw other people are having this problem too.